# aws chime - stretch video tile vertically

Tags: javascript, css, html5-video, aws-chime-sdk

Please be informed, we are using aws chime single js sdk to create a chat room. Its working perfectly fine but our  dimensions only increase proportionately for example its dimensions only work if it is 400 width and 250 height and not the other way with 400 height and 250 width.

For your information, attaching a image.
[image]
This is test video chat room. As you can see, the viewport dimensions is 400 width x 700 height. But the video tile only reaches 400px width and 250px height, which means it is only the quarter of the viewport's dimension. What i want is that tile should fully cover the viewport's dimension to 400w x 700h like the one in whatsapp video chat. We tried changing css dimensions like object-fit:cover, max-height, max-width. Created a wrapper div under video tag, but none of them works for us. Shall appreciate should you give us some clues on this issue.